# Vega: x-axis bar ploted out of range

Tags: vega

I'm just trying to draw a grouped bar chart with Vega. But the bar that drew on the x-axis out of the range.
I tried to check the code but with limited knowledge of Vega, I failed. :-(
Here is my code. What I'm trying to do is to draw a vertical bar chat of value grouped by the country code which variable name is "category":

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic grouped bar chart example.",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
    {"position": "0", "value": "0.017220172", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/10/21"},
    {"position": "1", "value": "0.026153846", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/5/21"},
    {"position": "2", "value": "0.031484258", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/6/3"},
    {"position": "3", "value": "0.022488756", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/6/17"},
    {"position": "4", "value": "0.024390244", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/7/2"},
    {"position": "5", "value": "0.015130674", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/7/29"},
    {"position": "6", "value": "0.017173052", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/8/26"},
    {"position": "7", "value": "0.025510204", "category": "ARG", "snapshots": "2020/9/24"},
    {"position": "0", "value": "0.002949853", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/10/21"},
    {"position": "1", "value": "0.012944984", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/5/21"},
    {"position": "2", "value": "0.018987342", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/6/3"},
    {"position": "3", "value": "0.006309148", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/6/17"},
    {"position": "4", "value": "0.003125", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/7/2"},
    {"position": "5", "value": "0.009202454", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/7/29"},
    {"position": "6", "value": "0.011976048", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/8/26"},
    {"position": "7", "value": "0.00295858", "category": "BRA", "snapshots": "2020/9/24"},
    {"position": "0", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/10/21"},
    {"position": "1", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/5/21"},
    {"position": "2", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/6/3"},
    {"position": "3", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/6/17"},
    {"position": "4", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/7/2"},
    {"position": "5", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/7/29"},
    {"position": "6", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/8/26"},
    {"position": "7", "value": "0", "category": "CAN", "snapshots": "2020/9/24"},
    {"position": "0", "value": "0.002159827", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/10/21"},
    {"position": "1", "value": "0.0302267", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/5/21"},
    {"position": "2", "value": "0.024813896", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/6/3"},
    {"position": "3", "value": "0.009975062", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/6/17"},
    {"position": "4", "value": "0.00486618", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/7/2"},
    {"position": "5", "value": "0.01891253", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/7/29"},
    {"position": "6", "value": "0.004555809", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/8/26"},
    {"position": "7", "value": "0.013274336", "category": "CHL", "snapshots": "2020/9/24"},
    {"position": "0", "value": "0.010989011", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/10/21"},
    {"position": "1", "value": "0.016393443", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/5/21"},
    {"position": "2", "value": "0", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/6/3"},
    {"position": "3", "value": "0", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/6/17"},
    {"position": "4", "value": "0.014492754", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/7/2"},
    {"position": "5", "value": "0", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/7/29"},
    {"position": "6", "value": "0.024096386", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/8/26"},
    {"position": "7", "value": "0.011494253", "category": "COL", "snapshots": "2020/9/24"}
    ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.2
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "value"},
      "range": "height",
      "round": true,
      "zero": true,
      "nice": true
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "position"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category20"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale"},
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale", "tickSize": 2, "labelPadding": 4, "zindex": 1}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",

      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "data": "table",
          "name": "facet",
          "groupby": "category"
        }
      },

      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"}
        }
      },
      "scales": [
        {
          "name": "pos",
          "type": "band",
          "range": "width",
          "domain": {"data": "facet", "field": "position"}
        }
      ],

      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "bars",
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "type": "rect",
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"scale": "pos", "field": "position"},
              "width": {"scale": "pos", "band": 1},
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "value"},
              "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "position"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the result that I got:
[image: X-axis out of the x scale range]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post:
https://gist.github.com/AlexAbes/c17703ce10f7f4a272324ea317e7afce;
The x-scale needs to be updated.

```
  "signals": [
    {"name": "width", "update": "bandwidth('xscale')"}
  ],
```